# Adobe AIR HTML Component, Load local app HTML, but allow remote (http) script and content

Tags: html, apache-flex, air, sandbox

I'm looking to load an included html file into a Flex HTML component in my AIR application, and that html file will include references to remote content. The default setup in AIR is to not allow this - content loaded locally from application then disabled remote content being allowed.

I've seen in their documentation that it looks like it's possible to change this, but I cannot find (after digging all over) how to do this.

From their documentation:

> The origin of the content in a page determines the sandbox to which it
>   is consigned. Only content loaded from the application directory (the
>   installation directory referenced by the app: URL scheme) is placed in
>   the application sandbox. Content loaded from the file system is placed
>   in the local-with-filesystem or the local-trusted sandbox, which
>   allows access and interaction with content on the local file system,
>   but not remote content. Content loaded from the network is placed in a
>   remote sandbox corresponding to its domain of origin.
>
> HTML pages in the application sandbox cannot use the script tag to
>   load JavaScript files from outside of the the application directory.
>   In order for a page in your application to load a script from outside
>   of the application directory, the page must be mapped to a
>   non-application sandbox.

That's great but how do I achieve this?

Looking to load a local file (app:/google-maps/capture.html) but allow remote content () so that google maps works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_11.html

The section "Loading application content into a non-application sandbox" answered it.

The solution:

I needed two html files, the one loaded into flex contains nothing more than an iframe, that attempts to load the actual file that I want displayed.

capture2.html (loaded into HTML component)

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%"
    src="capture.html"
    sandboxRoot="http://google.com/"
    documentRoot="app:/google-map-capture/">
    </iframe>
```

Then in the file that I actually want shown (capture.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Works perfectly.